# mongoose find query based on priority

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, find

I have a studentsubject schema.
Properties are subject_id,student_id,class_id

So my usecase is i want to find the one student where class_id, student_id matches. Subject id is optional. Means if subject id is present with that student and class id , then pick that student where all 3 id : class id,student id and subject id matches (because it is priority). Else pick the student where student id and class id matches, subject id might be different.

Ps: there might be multiple documents with same class id and student id. If we include subject id then it identify one document.

I tried this one

```
studentsubject.findone({
    student_id: studentId,
    class_id : classId,
    $or:[
        {
            subject_id : subjectId
        },
        {
            subject_id : {$exists:true}
        }
    ]
})
```

It fetches the first matched  document where class id and student id matches, not looking for existing data where subject id matches

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use a JS script. This one should work for your example:

```js
db = db.getSiblingDB('YOURDB');

const results = db.studentsubject.findOne({ student_id: studentId, class_id: classId, subject_id: subjectId });

if (results) {
  print(results);
} else {
  print(db.events.findOne({ student_id: studentId, class_id: classId, subject_id: { $exists: true } }));
}
```

Then you can run this script by using `load('path/to/script.js')`. Obviously, you need to provide the values, because in this script studentId, classId and subjectId are undefined.

Comment: Thanks @codetocode for answer, i want to do this in single query.

Answer (score 0):

> It fetches the first matched document where class id and student id matches, not looking for existing data where subject id matches

Its because you are giving an `or` statement `subject_id : {$exists:true}`. your query states:

*Match student_id, match class_id, and match subject_id*

OR

*Match student_id, match class_id, and just check if the document is assigned a subject_id **irrespective of its value***

It will result in whichever of the two it encounters first.

### Solution - Use Aggregations

```
db.demo.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      firstCond: [
        {
          $match: {
            student_id: "1",
            class_id: "A",
            subject_id: "Math"
          }
        }
      ],
      secondCond: [
        {
          $match: {
            student_id: "1",
            class_id: "A"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      docs: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $gt: [{ $size: "$firstCond" }, 0] },
          then: "$firstCond",
          else: "$secondCond"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$docs"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$docs" }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  }
])
```

### Explanation

`$facet` is used to create multiple sets of document criteria. `firstCond` checks if all 3 matches, `secondCond` checks if `student_id` and `class_id` matches, irrespective of `subject_id` value. `$project` shapes the output in a field/variable named `docs`. Then it checks if `firstCond` got any outputs or not (`$gt: 0`). If it does gives an output, then assign output of `firstCond` to `docs`, else assign output of `secondCond` to `docs`.

Now note the `documents` field is an array, so the `$unwind` is used to deconstruct it. `$replaceRoot` makes `docs` field to the top level as it is nested in another field. `$limit` as `1` only return the first matched of all documents. As there can be multiple in for example when `secondCond` results are used.

Lets take this sample data:

```json
[
  {
    "student_id": "1",
    "class_id": "A",
    "subject_id": "Math",
    "student_name": "Tony"
  },
  {
    "student_id": "2",
    "class_id": "B",
    "subject_id": "English",
    "student_name": "Natasha"
  },
  {
    "student_id": "1",
    "class_id": "A",
    "subject_id": "Science",
    "student_name": "Tony"
  }
]
```

On giving `student_id` as `1`, `class_id` as `A`, and `subject_id` as "Science" it outputs this:

```
{
    "student_id": "1",
    "class_id": "A",
    "subject_id": "Science",
    "student_name": "Tony"
}
```

but on giving `student_id` as `1`, `class_id` as `A`, and `subject_id` as `English` it outputs this:

```
{
    "student_id": "1",
    "class_id": "A",
    "subject_id": "Math",
    "student_name": "Tony"
}
```

Refer to [$cond](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) and [$facet](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) for reference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the answer you suggested db.demo.findOne({
    student_id: "1",
    class_id : "A",
    subject_id : "English"
})
will doesn't return any student. My question was if we are not able to find any student, get the student where student id and class id matches irrespective of subject id , if "English" is present then get that document because it is my first priority.

Comment: @GMadhabanandaPatra I apologize for the confusion. I looked up the documentation and examples as I knew there'd be a method to use `aggregate` for getting your desired results. I've updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: i saw your latest answer pretty much clear. Can you compare performance score between facet aggregation and two simple findone query for this type of question. Like i can simply use .findone(student_id,subject_id,class_id) if student is not present, i will go for another.findone(student_id,class_id) subject id might be anything

Comment: @GMadhabanandaPatra For large database two findOne operations means two round trips to the database, which increases network overhead. While facet aggregation grabs output for all subqueries simultaneously, and then the conditions decide which one to return. findOne also have its benefit that, it outputs the first match. If the first findOne does get a match, it will return it. While aggregation grabs all outputs, then uses `$limit: 1` to return the first document of all the matched.

Comment: Right. I checked with both the performance. The solution you sent is taking 600 ms and simple query is taking 10 ms for small database. I think your solution will fit for larger database.